# Rails 4 + ActiveAdmin passing params to another model and creating an object (with relations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, strong-parameters

Total Rails novice here, just coming from PHP.

I'm running a Rails4+Active Admin setup with (device/cancan  (disregarding those now).
Implementing strong_parameters. Please note, the code is totally broken. I've tried it in a bunch of ways and this is as close as I've gotten. Hopefully it gives a view into what I'm trying to do.

Been following a tutorial on implementing an API key setup, and trying to modify it to be able to generate an APIKey for a user in the admin.
I've added a column to AdminUser to generate an APIKey 
It is correctly linked to

```
#app/admin/admin_users.rb
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  index do 
      column :email
      column :current_sign_in_at
      column :last_sign_in_at
      column :sign_in_count
      default_actions
      column('API', :sortable => :id) { |resource|  link_to  "(Re)Generate Key",  new_admin_admin_user_api_key_path(resource.id)   }  
  end
end
```

Which gives me a (correct) link to
/admin/admin_users/:admin_user_id/api_keys/new(.:format)

```
# app/admin/api_key.rb
ActiveAdmin.register APIKey do
  belongs_to :admin_user

  controller do
    def create_for admin_user
      key = APIKey.new
      key.assign_params_from_controller(admin_user)
      APIKey.create(:admin_user_id => params[:admin_user_id]);
    end

    def permitted_params
      params.permit create_for [:admin_user_id]
    end
  end
end


#app/models/api_key.rb
class APIKey < ActiveRecord::Base  
before_create :generate_access_token
belongs_to :admin_user, :foreign_key => "id", :inverse_of => :api_key
attr_accessible :admin_user_id

def assign_params_from_controller(params)
  @params = params
end
private
def generate_access_token
  begin
    self.admin_user_id = params.admin_user_id
    self.access_token = SecureRandom.hex
  end while self.class.exists?(admin_user_id: admin_user_id, acces_token: access_token)
end
```

end

This code gives me:

```
NameError in Admin::APIKeysController#new
undefined local variable or method `params' for #<APIKey:0x000000078d6470>

def generate_access_token
  begin
    self.admin_user_id = params.admin_user_id
    self.access_token = SecureRandom.hex
  end while self.class.exists?(admin_user_id: admin_user_id, acces_token: access_token)
end
```

**UPDATE, ANSWER:**

Problem solved.

Ended up being on the right track. But was straying off because of type conversion errors.
My admin_user_id ended up being a 'string' in the database. Nice copy-paste job there.
Wrote a migration first

```
class AlterTableAPIKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "DELETE FROM `api_keys` WHERE 1"

    change_column :api_keys, :access_token,  :string, { null: false } 
    change_column :api_keys, :admin_user_id,  :integer, { null: false } 
    add_column :api_keys, :active, :boolean, {null: false, default: true }
    remove_column :api_keys, :role

    add_index :api_keys, ["admin_user_id"], name: "index_api_keys_on_admin_user_id", unique: false
    add_index :api_keys, ["access_token"], name: "index_api_keys_on_access_token", unique: true
  end
end
```

I didn't pass the access_token to the create.

I ended up with this.

```
# app/admin/api_key.rb
ActiveAdmin.register APIKey do
  belongs_to :admin_user
  controller do
    def new 
      key = APIKey.create(:admin_user_id => params[:admin_user_id])
        {:access_token => key.access_token}
      redirect_to admin_admin_users_path, :notice => "API Key #{key.access_token} created! " 
    end
    def permitted_params
      params.permit api_key: [:admin_user_id]
    end
  end
end

# app/models/api_key.rb
class APIKey < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :access_token, :expires_at, :admin_user_id, :active, :application
  before_create :generate_access_token
  before_create :set_expiration
  belongs_to :admin_user

  def expired?
    DateTime.now >= self.expires_at
  end

private
  def generate_access_token
    begin
      self.access_token = SecureRandom.hex
    end while self.class.exists?(access_token: access_token)
  end

  def set_expiration
    self.expires_at = DateTime.now+30
  end
```

end

Obviously this does not account for access, might solve that with roles (i.e. uberadmin can regenerate other admins API, admins only their own).

Comment: hi Kudami, welcome to SO. Please post you answer in an answer, and not in the question body itself and then mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, and thanks! SO didn't allow me to answer my own questions. (reputation thing).